# Orthogonal Trajectory to the given surface

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the trajectory on the surface $x^2+y^2+2fyz+d=0$ of its curve of intersection with planes parallel to $xy$-plane.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE, I suggest to include more context in the question, for example, are $f,d$ constants? What would constitute a solution? Do you need an implicit equation or an explicit parametrization? And more importantly, show what have you tried or where exactly you get stuck, or even if you can't start, what are your preliminary thoughts and available tools!